# Code breaks when I replace a range with a variable

Tags: excel, vba, variables

This code works fine:

```
   ActiveCell.Formula = "=""From :"" & TEXT(MIN(D16:D104),""mm/dd/yyyy"")"
```

I want to replace D104 with a variable(nrows)

```
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=""From : & TEXT(MIN(D16:"" & (nrows)) & "",""mm/dd/yyyy"")"
```

nrows is defined as a string. I'm sure it's a syntax error but I can't figure it out.
thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If `nrows` is a row number (eg. 104), pls try `ActiveCell.Formula = "=""From :"" & TEXT(MIN(D16:D" & nrows & "),""mm/dd/yyyy"")"`. If `nrows` is a cell reference (D104), pls try `ActiveCell.Formula = "=""From :"" & TEXT(MIN(D16:" & nrows & "),""mm/dd/yyyy"")"`.

Comment: "NRows is defined as a string" ... what is it's value? By the name, we would expect it to be a number (as in *number of rows*) ... which makes us old salts crazy because the naming is confusing!

Comment: Your quoting is different in the second (variable) version. I'm not at a machine to test ... but the double quotes after D16 look late and  suspect. Need some after the colon?

Comment: @taller you are correct in assuming nrows is a number and your solution works perfectly.  Thanks for helping out